# Referencing recently used objects in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My question refers to redundant code and a problem that I've been having with a lot of my R-Code.

Consider the following:

```
list_names<-c("putnam","einstein","newton","kant","hume","locke","leibniz")

combined_df_putnam$fu_time<-combined_df_putnam$age*365.25
combined_df_einstein$fu_time<-combined_einstein$age*365.25
combined_df_newton$fu_time<-combined_newton$age*365.25
...
combined_leibniz$fu_time<-combined_leibniz$age*365.25
```

I am trying to slim-down my code to do something like this:

```
list_names<-c("putnam","einstein","newton","kant","hume","locke","leibniz")
paste0("combined_df_",list_names[0:7]) <-  data.frame("age"=1)
paste0("combined_df_",list_names[0:7]) <-  paste0("combined_df_",list_names[0:7])$age*365.25
```

When I try to do that, I get "target of assignment expands to non-language object".
Basically, I want to create a list that contains descriptors, use that list to create a list of dataframes/lists and use these shortcuts again to do calculations. Right now, I am copy-pasting these assignments and this has led to various mistakes because I failed to replace the "name" from the previous line in some cases.

Any ideas for a solution to my problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could put you data.frames in a list and iterate over the list...

Comment: it's a bit hard to comprehend your question without a reproducible example. Could you provide some toy data example we can play with?

Answer (score 2):

The central problem is that you are trying to assign a value (or data.frame) to the *result of a function*.

In `paste0("combined_df_",list_names[0:7]) <-  data.frame("age"=1)`, the left-hand-side returns a character vector:

```
> paste0("combined_df_",list_names[0:7])
[1] "combined_df_putnam"   "combined_df_einstein" "combined_df_newton"  
[4] "combined_df_kant"     "combined_df_hume"     "combined_df_locke"   
[7] "combined_df_leibniz"
```

R will not just interpret these strings as variables that should be created and be referenced to. For that, you should look at the function `assign`.

Similarily, in the code `paste0("combined_df_",list_names[0:7])$age*365.25`, the `paste0` function does *not* refer to variables, but simply returns a character vector -- for which the `$` operator is not accepted.

There are many ways to solve your problem, but I will recommend that you create a function that performs the necessary operations of each data frame. The function should then return the data frame. You can then re-use the function for all 7 philosophers/scientists.

Comment: R *can* actually assign to the result of a function (well, a function call expression anyway) just fine, and it’s a fairly common idiom (consider `names(x) = …`). But that only works if the first argument in the function call is a variable name.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, Konrad Rudolph. I believe these are often referred to as "replacement functions"; commenly used, yes, but I wouldn't say there are many of them.